# Probability for selecting the right team

Tags: combinatorics

A 3-person basketball team consists of a guard, a
forward, and a center.
(a) If a person is chosen at random from each of
three different such teams, what is the probability
of selecting a complete team?
My approach to this question was :
$9*8*7$ for Guard,Forward,Center, but my answer is wrong dont know why.
The correct answer is 2/9. Can someone help me with the concept?

Comment: 987 here means 9*8*7, because 9 places for the first player, 8 places for the second player and so on

Comment: The probability cannot be larger than 1. Does not it seem strange to you?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Assume that you choose a person from the first team. What is the probability that you choose a player of other quality from the second team? What is then the probability that you choose the player of other quality than the previous two from the third team?

Comment: The probability that I choose a player of other quality from the second team is 1/3 ?

Comment: How have you come to this number?

Comment: Because only 1 out 3 guards/forwards/centre will be able to occupy 1st position. 
As there are total 3 guards, so probability will be 1/3.

Comment: Please explain me the concept if i m wrong

Comment: Now for the second person it will be 2/3. as for example the second guard will have the probability of 2/3.

Comment: Is your current version 2/3 or 1/3?

Comment: i m confused , please explain

Comment: There are red, green and blue balls in a bag. What is the probability that you draw not red (i.e. green or blue) ball?

Comment: So if the bag has 5R,4G,8B. The probability of not drawing a Red Ball is 12/17

Comment: Correct. Now apply the same logic to the case 1R1G1B.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 slots (teams), each can take 3 values (positions) independently of other positions: GGG, GFG, $\ldots$ CCC. So in total you have $3^3$ ways of filling them.
You have 3 outcomes that match the requirement: exactly one unique choice for each position. You have $3!$ such choices. Now divide it through the total number of choices to get the result.

Answer (score -1):

1. In the first choice I can chose any player: $p_1=1$
2. In the second choice I can chose any player but not the one chosed in 1. Then the probability is $p_2=\frac{2}{3}$
3. In the third choice I must chose the only type of player not chosen in 1. and 2. Then the probability is $p_3=\frac{1}{3}$

Concluding: the requested probability is

$$1\cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: can u also tell me for part b of the question:

Comment: What is the probability that all 3 players
selected play the same position?
I am trying 2/9+2/9+2/9 and getting wrong anwer

Comment: @MathsGeek : the solution for part b is $1\times \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{3}= \frac{1}{9}$

Comment: i m confused why are u taking 1

Comment: can u explain 1*1/3*1/3

Comment: @MathsGeek : first choice, any choice. Second and Third choice: same choice as in the first one...only 1 case on 3 possible

Comment: @MathsGeek : if  you are confused why taking 1 you can do $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times 3$ that is the same